# Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500)"

Tags: objective-c, iphone, afnetworking

I am using afnetworking in my application.

To post data on server I wrote following code

```
- (void) callLoginAPI:(NSDictionary *)dictProfile{
    // 1

    NSDictionary *params = @{@"username":[dictProfile valueForKey:@"name"],
                             @"first_name":[dictProfile valueForKey:@"first_name"],
                             @"last_name":[dictProfile valueForKey:@"last_name"],
                             @"email":[dictProfile valueForKey:@"email"],
                             @"dob":[dictProfile valueForKey:@"birthday"],
                             @"gender":[dictProfile valueForKey:@"gender"],
                             @"location":[[dictProfile valueForKey:@"location"] valueForKey:@"name"],
                             @"timezone":[dictProfile valueForKey:@"timezone"],
                             @"language":@"",
                             @"profile_pic_url":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large",[dictProfile valueForKey:@"id"]],
                             @"cover_pic_url":@""
                             };

    NSString* HOST_URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@login/",BASE_URL];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    operationManager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

    [operationManager POST:HOST_URL parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
        NSLog(@"resp:%@",responseObject);
        // Enter what happens here if successsful.

    }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
        NSLog(@"error:%@",error);
        // Enter what happens here if failure happens

    }];
}
```

But in response I got following error

```
error:Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500)" UserInfo=0x7cc8bb50 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7ca9d4d0> { URL: http://10.1.81.35:8000/api/login/ } { status code: 500, headers {
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Tue, 07 Oct 2014 08:25:40 GMT";
    Server = "WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.6";
    Vary = Cookie;
    "X-Frame-Options" = SAMEORIGIN;
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://10.1.81.35:8000/api/login/, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: internal server error (500),
```

I don't understand where I made mitake.
Any help would be appriciable.

Comment: I have the same issue, is it solved?

Comment: any solution for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're ok. Your server returns an error to your request. Code 500 usually means internal error such as unhandled exception. So it definitely has nothing to do with client.