# AFNetworking response not in proper format

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, laravel, afnetworking

i am using AFNetworking framework in the my project & accessing webservice via AFHTTPSessionManager class like following way,

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:30];

NSDictionary *parametersDictionary = @{
                             @"users_id":userIDStr,
                             @"name" :@""

                             };
[manager POST:@"api/call_XAPI?"
                                      parameters:parametersDictionary
                                        progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {

                                        }
                                         success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {                                                 
                                                                         NSLog(@"Success");                       

                                         } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
                                                                                                                     NSLog(@"%@", error);                
                                         }];
```

This is working properly on success but when if any error occurs in server then error response not getting in proper format on the console

```
Printing description of error:
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500)" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x608000435940> { URL: http://www.example.com/api/call_XYZAPI? } { status code: 500, headers {
"Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Type" = "application/json";
Date = "Mon, 30 Jan 2017 13:12:59 GMT";
Server = "nginx/1.10.2";
"Set-Cookie" = "laravel_session=ca9b0725b981267be1f095bb6ae14a1d5ae2825f; expires=Mon, 30-Jan-2017 15:12:59 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly";
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://www.example.com/api/call_XYZAPI?, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data = 12112,23131,31231331,312231 .....
```

**Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong & how to resolve this issue?**

Comment: it is giving error, better check first into postman if it gives complete response or not ?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26231780/error-domain-com-alamofire-error-serialization-response-code-1011-request-fail

Comment: which kind of response you are getting in response . add some format of that code.

Comment: Hello @KKRocks i have already added  `Printing description of error:` above

Comment: is this that format :  12112,23131,31231331,312231 .....

Comment: @KKRocks Yes getting lot of digits on console with above header section.

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/35083647/3901620

Comment: Hello @KKRocks that is what i am looking for. Its working now you saved my backend developer time.

Comment: ok enjoy and i have added this as my answer so if it is proper solution for  your question upvote tomy answer

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://www.lifewire.com/500-internal-server-error-explained-2622938), the error 500 has nothing to do with the client and should be handled on web service server.

Contact your backend developer and ask him to fix it.

Comment: Yes @Yogi you are correct,we already resolved this issue, But my question is error response is not in proper format.

Comment: I think you should have a look at contents of `NSHTTPURLResponse` object. Mostly it has the response from server in better format. I assume that you require it to let the user know about the error by presenting an error alert or so.

Comment: When you got a `internal server error (500) `, the terminal log as you printed is ok, do not worry about it.

Comment: Yeah @nynohu sir i have handled all status code too but i am just curious about error format.

Comment: You can `try NSHTTPURLResponse *response = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)task.response;
        int statuscode = response.statusCode;` for get error code

Comment: Yes @nynohu i already did it. But my question is this error format is correct when any error occurs from backend.